# Convert ArrayList < String> to ArrayList<SelectItem>

Tags: java, jsf

I have an `ArrayList<String>` named listout, I want to convert it to an `ArrayList<SelectItem>`. How can I do that?

PS: JSF's selectItem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean JSF's [`SelectItem`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html):

```
List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(listout.size());
for(String value : listout){
    items.add(new SelectItem(value));
}
return items;
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on your question history, you're using JSF 2. In this case, it's good to know that `<f:selectItem>` and `<f:selectItems>` do not require a single or a collection of `SelectItem` object(s) anymore. Just a plain vanilla `String` or even a Javabean is also perfectly fine.

So,

```
private String selectedItem;
private List<String> availableItems;

// ...
```

with

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

should work as good in JSF 2.

Or, a collection of Javabeans, assuming that `Foo` has properties `id` and `name`.

```
private Foo selectedItem;
private List<Foo> availableItems;

// ...
```

with

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" var="foo" itemValue="#{foo}" itemLabel="#{foo.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

#### See also:

- [Our `<selectOneMenu>` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what `SelectItem` is, so I will suppose you have a method for converting a `String` to it, named createSelectItem().

You have to iterate through the strings and fill another `ArrayList` :

```
ArrayList<SelectItem> out = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
for(String str : listout) {
    out.add(createSelectItem(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

[guava solution](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html):

```
    Collection<SelectItem> result = Collections2.transform(
        listout, 
        new Function<String, SelectItem>(){
           @Override
           public SelectItem apply(String s) {
            return  createSelectItem(s);
    }
});
```